# Roku: How to change label text size

Tags: roku, brightscript

Bright script using scene graph. i want to change size of default font without Font node. I used "SmallestSystemFont" font. It appears large font then actual require size.

```
<Label id="myLabel" width="200" height="200" text="Hello Label" font="font:SmallestSystemFont"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this code to the script, attached to your component:

```
myLabel = m.top.findNode("myLabel")
myLabel.font.size = 20
```

Every Label node has Font node inside. Thus you can simply access it and change its properties.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply

Comment: +1 since works but hacky since relies on font child being added. Can't they just add a nested <font/> element instead of after-patching?